# OpenID Integration

Tags: asp.net, openid

Does anyone know of an ASP.NET guide to implementing OpenID and what information can be returned by the OpenID provider? I understand you can get the email address but if someone logs in with their Google OpenID can you get access to their addresses?

Comment: Are you referring to getting their contacts?

Comment: more like if I have an e-commerce site and the user logs in with an open id it would be a nicer user experience if I could say do you want to use your billing address for your google account for example. 

I suppose my question really is, is open id purley an authentication provider or can it provide access to the providers meta data so for google accounts - billing and delivery addresses or for a aol open id - a list of your contacts to populate the email this product to your friend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OpenID Providers can and often do offer 'claims' or 'attributes' about the people logging in if the OpenID relying party requests them and the user consents to these data being shared.

If you use [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net) for your ASP.NET OpenID library, it has built-in support for several ways of getting these attributes but keeps it simple on your side to get at them regardless of which way the Provider offers them.  If you download the library it comes with a sample of how to do this.

As far as work address, and some other attributes specific to certain domains (domains of data--not Internet domains) very few Providers offer them.  The best you can do is get "full address" and ask the user if that's the one they want to use.

Comment: i m not able to open the link you have provided. please provide complete link as a text

Answer (score 0):

This should help: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/4b3c7c9b-fe80-4e6e-a34e-0e9efed5c575/integrate-openid-authenti.aspx

Or a "simpler" one: http://madskristensen.net/post/OpenID-implementation-in-Csharp-and-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[Document describes](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OpenID.html) how to implement Google login into your web application
and Third-party web sites and let you aware how OpenID authentication works.

[Here](http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/09/use-google-openid-authentication-in.html) is the step-by-step process to implement OpenID on your ASP.NET application using DotNetOpenOAuth libraray.

[Tutorial](http://danhounshell.com/blog/adding-openid-to-your-web-site-in-conjunction-with-asp-net-membership/) demonstrates how to add OpenID support to an existing site that already has traditional membership without breaking anything in AspDotNetMVC.

Answer (score 0):

I just blogged about this here. this shows how you can get extra information from these providers
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/22/extra-information-from-oauth-openid-provider.aspx