# How to integrate open ID Login

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, openid, dotnetopenauth

I want to integrate Open ID, Google and Yahoo login in my site, So please anyone can tell me the process of integration in **ASP.NET.**

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050473/openid-integration

Answer (score 0):

Google and Yahoo support OpenID, so you just need to OpenID enable your website.

This is a [great article](http://www.plaxo.com/api/openid_recipe) which tells you step by step of *what* you need to do. You will still need an OpenID library for .NET in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually written a blog post on [How to add OpenID authentication to your site using Janrain Engage](http://www.sharpedgesoftware.com/Blog/2011/02/21/how-to-add-openid-authentication-to-your-aspnet-mvc-3-site-using-janrain-engage) that might help you along.

It's written with an ASP.NET  MVC 3 application in mind, but there's nothing in there you cannot use in an ASP.NET app.