# How can I login into my asp.net website using gmail account?

Tags: authentication, gmail

I have an asp.net website with login form and I want every visitors can able to login into my website using their gmail account....

Is there any one who can assist me on this or send some examples for the same?

Thanks
Hitesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate open ID Login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198479/how-to-integrate-open-id-login)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for OpenID.  See http://www.fryan0911.com/2010/09/use-google-openid-authentication-in.html.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail uses a technology called 'open ID'.

I suggest you use a service like [Janrain](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage/social-login)

and they will take care of the open ID implementation for you.

Comment: Technically, they are an OpenID "Provider".