# Regarding login credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, openid

I have a website using ASP.NET and I want visitors to be able to login to my website using their gmail account.  What libraries or services do I need to be able to do this?

Comment: check out this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640216/create-a-website-to-login-in-with-your-gmail-yahoo-facebook-accounts

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113855/how-can-i-login-into-my-asp-net-website-using-gmail-account

Comment: This kind of authentication is called OpenID.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526890/best-openid-api-for-asp-net-mvc-application.

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpfull for you

http://openid.net/

use this, even StackOverflow is using the same.